# jquery scrollview simple example request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollview

I've been trying to get a basic scrollview working today and I must be missing something really basic.  I've looked at the demo pages, and downloaded the jquery.mobile.scrollview,js/cvss and the extra scrollview.js  you can see the other versions of scripts i'm running as well.  If i could have a really basic example as a self contained zip that i could look at, that would be awesome.

or maybe there is a little but of JS that i'm missing to init the scroller?

```
<link href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery/jquery.mobile.scrollview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/scrollview.js"></script>

...

<div id="vechileSearchResultsScroller" data-scroll="y">
      <ul id="vehicleSearchResults" data-role="listview" >
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
            <li>six</li>
            <li>seven</li>
            <li>eight</li>
            <li>nine</li>
            <li>ten</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to add the height to `parentNode`, in this case is `#vechileSearchResultsScroller`
2. try to add this code in your web

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('#vechileSearchResultsScroller').scrollview({
           direction:'y'
       })
   })
   ```